# How to compare two arrays in Mocha?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

When I try

```
expect([1,2]).to.equal([1,2])
```

I get

```
AssertionError: expected [ 1, 2 ] to equal [ 1, 2 ]
```

probably due to object comparison?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use `deep` for a deep copy of actual attributes, e.g.

```
expect([1,2]).deep.to.equal([1,2]);


passes
```

Comment: I used `expect([1,2]).deep.equal([1,2])`

Comment: The answer didn't work for me, but the comment from @Fedorov7890 did.